# TFS GIT REST API get related work items of commit

Tags: git, tfs

I want to query GIT commits to get related works item IDs associated with particular commit. (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits)

Request:

```
http://{server}/tfs/{collection}/{git repository}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository name}/commits?api-version=1.0
```

Unfortunately it returns truncated comments and because of that it is not always possible to see work item ID (#{Work Item ID}).

```
{
    "count": 100,
    "value": [{
            "commitId": "commit hash",
            "author": {
                "name": "some name",
                "email": "some email",
                "date": "2016-12-12T14:29:28Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "some name",
                "email": "some email",
                "date": "2016-12-12T14:29:28Z"
            },
            "comment": "Merge branch 'someBranch' of something.",
            "commentTruncated": true,
            "changeCounts": {
                "Add": 5,
                "Edit": 34
            },
            "url": "url",
            "remoteUrl": "remoteUrl"
        }]
}
```

In the response above the property "commentTruncated" is set to true.
I have read the documentation, but did not find the solution to get either full comment or related work item separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask the detail of each commit, e.g.

`GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4?api-version=1.0`

See the [Just the commit](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits) section in the docs.

Comment: Thank you! It was not really what I was expecting, but if it is the only approach then I will go with it.